# npm command returns nothing nothing and says "command executed with exit code (1)"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I had nodejs reinstalled after uninstalling and now I just can't use npm. When I do node -v I get the proper version of node js, but when I do npm -v/ npm -version, nothing returns. When I use npm in vs code terminal, it says  `command executed now and failed(exit code 1)`.

In terminal when I do node -v I get this

```
C:\Users\krish> node -v
v18.16.0
```

when I do npm -v, nothing happens.

```
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish> npm -v
PS C:\Users\krish>
```

I can't use npm at all. Nothing with npm works. I tried uninstalling node js and deleting files/folders and everything. When I uninstall node js the npm command shows an error saying the comandlet is unrecognised. But after installation, npm does nothing.

Please HELP!

Comment: Remove the existing Nodejs from the system and reinstall the latest version from the official site.